# How to add images to JQuery autocomplete which also fills hidden data inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to add images to JQuery autocomplete which also fills hidden data inputs?

Comment: What is the element supposed to hold the flag picture?

Comment: It's not part of the page itself but rather generated by the JQuery <li>, or that is how I understood these things are done. Did that answer your question or am I onto something else? I've added an example JFiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You want the image to show inside the input?

Comment: That is correct. When the user starts with an "S" for example, the Spanish and Serbian flags will show before or after the suggested items "Spain" and "Serbia".

Comment: Your example fiddle should help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks I'll try more and let you know. Though I have been messing with it for some time. The result is that the entire JQuery suggestion stops working and Chrome starts suggesting stuff offline.

Comment: Chek this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naoadLg9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
this.form.pictureElementContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="path/to/' + ui.item.Flag + '" />';
```

where `pictureElementContainer` is the HTML element within your form that will hold the image.

As per your edit and fiddle:

```
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
  return $("<li></li>").data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<img src="' + item.Flag + '" /> ').appendTo(ul);
};
```

or something along those lines...

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naoadLg9/)</kbd>

Comment: you don't need to write the open and close tag, just use $('<li/>'). It would also be cleaner to create an img element like this: $('<img/>').attr('src', url)

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to use the power of JQuery:

**To set the value of an input field:**

`$('input').val(value);`

**to attach a new image:**

`$('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://url/1.png').attachTo('#img-container');`